# How to send Notifications to all clients connected in Cordova Socket IO from a single Nodejs Socket IO Server HTML

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, socket.io

I'm trying to send a single message to all connected clients from a server running Nodejs+Socket IO.

**Client :**

Client side is a cordova based Notifications display screen with all necessary css + angularjs + Cordova Socket IO codings that connects to server socket IO and only accepts message from the server.

**Server :**

Server side is a Nodejs based Notifications server with all necessary Expressjs + Socket IO codings that connects to clients socket IO and only Sends message from the server. Server is in a separate Ubuntu server machine.

Now I have hard-coded the message in server as "var msg = 'Hi, this is Notification!';" and the server serves this message via socket io to all connected clients. If I change this message of-course the message is notified to the clients who is connected.

My requirement is to send notifications differently from a webpage form as admin to all clients. But this webpage should not be visible to the clients only the message reaches the Clients.

Please help any Idea!!

Answer (score 1):

Is the admin sending messages from a different web page? if so, you can open a socket connection from there and broadcast the messages to all the connected socket clients

```
socket.on('admMsg', function(data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit("admMsg", data.msg);
});
```

And on the admin page client side

```
var socket = io.connect();
function sendMsg() {
    var admMsg = $("#txtMsg").val();
    var msg = {
        msg: admMsg
    };

socket.emit('admMsg', msg);

}
```

Please let me know if I am missing out something.

Comment: Thank u. But, in my case I have a single nodejs+socket IO server which send a html form file to only the Admin not to all Clients. Clients connected to same server can only receive the admins message not the html form from server. Say for eg. client access the server "var socket = io.connect(URL);" where URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000";. Please Help!

Comment: I got the answer. Thanks for the answers. The solution for my problem is based upon the url. I've used only socket.emit to transfer the message. It worked for me. After a lot of study in socket IO MY PROJECT IS COMPLETE. Thank you.